# 'HttpResponse.Data' and the 'results' attribute values of executed breeze query are different

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, breeze

I'm currently using BreezeJs in an asp.net web application and identified that 'HttpResponse.Data' and the 'results' attribute values of executed breeze query are different in random cases.

The identified scenario: when the database is manually updated using a stored-procedure and set several data records values to empty.

```
return EntityQuery.from('SampleEndpointName')
                            .withParameters({ Id: sampleId})
                            .using(self.manager)
                            .execute()
                            .then(querySucceeded, this._queryFailed);

        function querySucceeded(data) {
            var sampleData;
            if (data.results.length > 0) {
                sampleData = data.results;
            }

            return sampleData;
```

In above-mentioned scenario, a network call triggers and fetch the correct values but not updates 'results' of returned breeze object. The 'results' retain previous values. Tried adding  `.using(MergeStrategy.OverwriteChanges);` but didn't work. Any clues on fixing this issue?

Comment: Does this happen when the stored proc changes the values to _anything_, or only when it changes the values to null?  Does your server-side JSON serialization include null properties when sending responses back to the client?